# Pass view id or reference in databinding method reference

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I have an xml with multiple TextInputLayouts. One of them goes as follows:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textInputEmail"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin_half"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin_half"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:text="@={viewModel.username}"
                    android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.onTextChanged(text)}"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

---

In my viewmodel I have text change listener implemented as follows:

---

```
    fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence){
    Log.i("LoginViewModel", "username = "+text)
}
```

---

What I want to do is something like this:

```
    fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence, view: View){
    when(view.id){
        R.id.editText1 -> doSomething1()
        R.id.editText2 -> doSomething2()
}
```

---

Is it possible to pass view/id/reference of the view that triggered the method, when databinding is used to call methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can pass your views in databinding, simply create a method with `View` a parameter in the view model:

```
fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence, view: View){
    when(view.id) {
        R.id.editText1 -> doSomething1()
        R.id.editText2 -> doSomething2()
    }
}
```

Then pass the view's id to the method in XML layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:text="@={viewModel.username}"
    android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.onTextChanged(text, editTextEmail)}"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. That did the trick. I didn't know that we can use id of view for method calls

Comment: Also, If the id is like "edit_text_email", you have to pass this as "editTextEmail".